# Цикл который проходит через все Radiobutton пропускается во время выполнения

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, foreach

Есть код, который, по идее, должен работать:

```
foreach(RadioButton rb in groupBox1.Controls)
        {
            rb.Image = img_a[rand.Next(0, 13)];  // На Radiobutton должна прикреплятся картинка,
        }                                       // из img_a выбранная рандомно
```

Но при запуске программы картинок на картинок нет, причем в отладке выполнение доходит до цикла `foreach`, подсвечивает его и выполнение продолжается дальше, пробовал менять панель для кнопок, пробовал без нее, оставляя кнопки на форме, но результат один и тот же

Comment: `foreach(RadioButton rb in groupBox1.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>())`

Comment: @Bulson, ничего не поменялось. Все еще пропускает

Comment: Что значит пропускает? Не заходит в цикл? Или что? Пишите яснее, здесь нет экстрасенсов.

Comment: @Bulson вот ссылка на видео: https://radikal.ru/video/ibRKlssKshD

Comment: Вы когда заходите в цикл и останавливаетесь на `in`, то в открытой вкладке внизу "Видимые" можете найти и посмотреть (развернуть) количество элементов в `groupBox1.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>()`. Раз в цикл не заходит, значит в `groupBox1` нет радиокнопок, тут нечего больше решать. Не ленитесь давать нормальные названия контролам, а не подобно этому убогому `groupBox1`.

Comment: @Bulson и правда, после перестановки кнопок все заработало, спасибо, но изображения на кнопки все еще не ставятся. Через цикл теперь проходит нормально: https://ibb.co/BjcQMY1 В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Пример работы]

В качестве контейнера для картинок используется `ImageList`

```
public partial class MainView : Form
{
    private static Random _random = new Random();

    public MainView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.Text = "Пример отображения картинок и радиокнопок";

        _buttonChange.Click += ButtonChange_Click;
    }

    private void ButtonChange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int maxIndex = _imageList.Images.Count;

        foreach (var rButton in _groupBox.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>())
        {
            rButton.Image = _imageList.Images[_random.Next(0, maxIndex)];
        }
    }
}
```